# How to select data from three tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am developing an application in c# in which I have to fetch data from 3 tables. i.e (emp_id, emp_name, emp_fname) from employs table, (designation_name) from designation table and (date) from emp_attendance table. How to do it. The employs table and designation table are in relationship. My interface and database is below.

Application Interface:
[image: Application Interface]

employs table:
[image: employs table]

designation table:
[image: designation table]

employ_attendance table:
[image: employ_attendance table]

Comment: Do you want to use SQL or Linq?

Comment: One word for you: JOIN.  Learn SQL.

Comment: -1 - it seems the OP did not make any attempt at learning SQL and JOINs. This is a very simple and elementary question which can be easily answered by reading any of the SQL tutorials on the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a join:

```
Select Column1,
       Column 2,
       Column 3
From   TableA
Join   TableB
On     Column1 = Column2
Join   TableC
On     Column2 = Column3
```

Comment: I know but how to use join for these three tables?